# How to include an item to items group only if there wasn't such an item?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to implement a simple MSBuild "plugin" for MS VS C++ environment. It should utilise some utility which, in turn, converts text files written on certain language into C-sources.

And I faced with trouble of how to add the generated C-files dynamically into the C-compiler's input items-list in case of files with the same name already exist in the VS project. I'm trying to achieve this via the following line in my `.targets` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="%(MyCompiler.Outputs)" Condition="???" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but I'm not sure, how to compose the conditional part to reach the goal. Any conditions I tried lead to that the generated files is being added and VS throws the warning:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1091,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of <FileName>.c will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are <FileName>.c, <FileName>.c.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Exclude` attribute and the ItemGroup itself can be excluded, e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="%(MyCompiler.Outputs)" Exclude="@(ClCompile)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

An item in the `Include` that matches with an item in the `Exclude` will not be added to the ItemGroup.

As an example:
Assume @(ClCompile) consists of "A.c;B.c" and %(MyCompiler.Outputs) consists of "C.c;A.c". The code above evaluates to

```
<ClCompile Include="C.c;A.c" Exclude="A.c;B.c" />
```

"A.c" will not be added (and duplicated) because it is in the Exclude set. The new value of @(ClCompile) will be "A.c;B.c;C.c".

Comment: Then, will all previous members of the `ClCompile` be excluded? It's not a desired behaviour. I need to add an item, but only if there wasn't (added by hand via the development environment) an item with the same name.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more detail. Thanks

Comment: I found one more way: there is the `KeepDuplicates` attribute. It should be set to `False` for the Item in order to achieve the goal.

Comment: Be aware that `KeepDuplicates` uses the metadata when comparing. Two items with the same `Identity` and different metadata will not be duplicates. The `Exclude` is comparing the `Identity` only.